# How to calculate the duration in seconds if a date is written in the following format: "2022-03-10T09:40:44.543Z"

Tags: sql, date, time

I have just imported in SQL an excel file which contains two columns `("Start Date" & "End Date")` with the following format:

```
"2022-03-10T09:40:44.543Z".
```

I would like to calculate the difference expressed in second between "Start Date" and "End Date".
Any suggestion please?

I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: What dbms are you using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17..

Comment: Have you tried https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e29c64fa9602860340e034a0753c5d1e ?

Comment: `SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is an integrated environment for managing any SQL infrastructure, from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database`. Are you using SQL Server ? Which version ?

Comment: I've just tried datediff and it works; thank you!

Comment: I added an answer with more explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server` you could try [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver18)

> Syntax
>
> ```
> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
> ```

In your case :

```
select DATEDIFF(Second,Start_Date,End_Date) as difference;
```

If you have stored the data on text columns you could use:

```
select DATEDIFF(Second,  CONVERT(varchar,Start_Date,127), CONVERT(varchar,End_Date,127) ) as difference;
```

Check [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=569cac4efa0becee083808baa5c145de) for more details

Check the [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) date  styles